# dialogflow multi-select entities

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

This is probably an easy issue.
I have an intent:

[image]

As you can see I have some trainging phrases which currently match to an entity, but as you can see it is creating mutiple parameters for each one:

- questions
- questions2
- questions3

What I actually want it to do, is know that `brand, colour and fit` are all of the same entity type.
Is that possible?

The reason I want this, is there might be 1 or there might be 10 and I would prefer not to have questions1-10...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this one out myself :)
It turns out the "Is list" option is what is required here.
[image]